# wine for ubuntu 9.10

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, wine

I tried to use wine for ubuntu 9.04 in my ubuntu 9.10. But when I tried to use portable keypass(password manager), it does not work. Is there a wine for ubuntu 9.10? Can I use it to install windows-based programs/apps on ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By "portable keypass" you mean keepassx, then it's a standard package in the ubuntu repo.

```
sudo apt-get install keepassx
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes wine does support 9.10, you can find out more at [winehq.org](http://winehq.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You should check which repositories you have enabled in the package manager.

There are two versions of Wine in the official repos for this release of Ubuntu: version 1.0.1-0ubuntu8, based on the stable release, in the universe repository as the package simply called `wine` and version 1.1.31-0ubuntu3, based on a later beta, in the multiverse repository as the package `wine1.2`.

So if you have the Universe repository enabled you should find Wine in the standard package managers, or can more manually install it with `sudo aptitude install wine` from a shell command line. Remove any version you have already installed first from other sources though, to avoid confusion.